# Push from database

Tags: python, postgresql

I am writing a simple telegram bot that will remind people of the pills they should be taking at this time. I already have version 1 but I'm wondering the best solution for creating notifications. I also have to check if the pill is "paused" so my queries are a little heavy. My goal is to get data from the DB by some kind of push. It can be any PostgreSQL related mechanism, or I can do it somehow with message queues, or any code level algorithm/solution.

I now have a `notification time` object in the DB associated with the pill containing the time and additional information, and I simply pull these objects from the DB every X seconds.

Comment: I also got an idea of copying data to redis every hour or so and then working with redis

Answer (score 1):

Have the notification system query the database for a time window of notifications, ordered by the notification time. Give it a little buffer to account for query time and loading. For example, if it's 11:59 it might query for `where 12:00 <= notify_at and notify_at < 12:10 and status <> 'paused' order by notify_at asc`. At 12:09 it queries for `where 12:10 <= notify_at and notify_at < 12:20 ...`.

Make sure you have an multi-column index on `(notify_at, status)` so the filtering and sorting all happens efficiently on an index.

Then the notification system uses the buffer.

```
Database -> Buffer -> Notification System
```

How large the window and buffer is depends on the size of your data. If it's fairly small and you only have one notification process, you can use a small window and store the results in process memory. If it is large, you could load it into a [redis event queue](https://redis.com/redis-best-practices/communication-patterns/event-queue/).